# Is there any resource for UI examples?

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns

I run a Usability/UX blog, and my biggest hurdle right now is finding examples to illustrate the topics I write about (bad error messages, good implementation of tabs, bad interactions...etc)

So is there a website that has, for example, a database of categorized/tagged interface screenshots from various web sites on the web?

Comment: Not an answer, so I will just put it as a comment.  I haven't seen something like you are describing.  I blog about UX frequently, so I know what you mean.  http://commadot.com

Answer (score 14):

These are the pattern repositories I find myself referring to most often:

- [Designing Interfaces](http://designinginterfaces.com/)
- [Yahoo! Design Pattern Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/)
- [Quince: UX Patterns Explorer](http://quince.infragistics.com/)
- [Pattern Tap](http://patterntap.com/)
- [UI Patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/)
- [Welie Interaction Design Pattern Library](http://www.welie.com/patterns/)
- [Designing Social Interfaces Wiki](http://www.designingsocialinterfaces.com/patterns.wiki/index.php?title=Main%5FPage)

It's also worth having a look at various operating system interface guidelines for inspiration:

- [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/XHIGIntro.html)
- [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx)
- [GNOME Human Interface Guidelines](http://library.gnome.org/devel/hig-book/stable/)

Finally, if you're looking for some good books on the subject, the O'Reilly "Designing Interfaces" series is a great collection of pattern libraries:

- [Designing Interfaces](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596008031/)
- [Designing Web Interfaces](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516253/)
- [Designing Social Interfaces](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596154936/)
- [Designing Gestural Interfaces](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596518394/)

There quite a few more design pattern resources out there, but these are the resources that I've found to be the most useful.

Comment: Thank you very much, I voted for your reply since it's very useful, but it's not really what I'm looking for. The design pattern was just an example.

I've modified the original post to make it clearer now.

Answer (score 7):

Some suggestions on pattern libraries:

- http://patterntap.com/
- http://www.welie.com/patterns/index.php
- http://ui-patterns.com/
- http://uipatternfactory.com/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/
- http://www.flickr.com/photos/factoryjoe/collections/72157600001823120/
- http://wearecolorblind.com/
- http://searchpatterns.org/Main_Page
- http://www.scrnshots.com/
- http://osdpl.fluidproject.org/
- http://www.flickr.com/groups/uxpatterns/
- http://www.flickr.com/groups/uxerrors/
- http://www.flickr.com/groups/dailyux/
- http://www.flickr.com/groups/uxpatterns/

Answer (score 6):

You asked for examples of good and bad web elements of various kinds.

Here are some resources from which you can draw examples, screenshots, ideas of sites to look at, etc., on which to make ux-specific commentary:

- [Time Magazine's 5 Worst Websites](http://www.time.com/time/specials/2007/article/0,28804,1638344%5F1638341,00.html)
- [Time Magazine's 50 Best Websites 2009](http://www.time.com/time/specials/packages/article/0,28804,1918031%5F1918016,00.html)
- [Top 10 Worst Websites You'll Wish you Hadn't seen](http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/top-10-worst-websites/)
- [Web Pages That Suck](http://www.webpagesthatsuck.com/worst-business-web-sites-of-2009-but-you-can-learn-something-from-them.html#axzz0e7smhIXD) ('Worst of' by year, from 2005-2009)
- [The World's Worst Website](http://www.angelfire.com/super/badwebs/)

Comment: Thanks Nathalie! although this isn't exactly what I'm looking for, but it will be a great resource for me to build my own collection of screenshots and ideas.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there are plenty more, but my favorite resource for this type of data is [Pattern Tap](http://patterntap.com/).

Comment: Thanks! that looks pretty nice, too bad their search capability is weak though. :(

Answer (score 3):

I have about 30 sites linked from my Delicious acct: http://delicious.com/FiveFifteen/patterns

Answer (score 2):

Here's a huge collection of patterns: [40+ Helpful Resources On User Interface Design Patterns](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but what I'm looking for isn't limited to design patterns only. I also look for things like "bad error messages", "tedious sign up form"...etc

Answer (score 2):

Check this one too : [25 UI Inspiration and Design Pattern Resources by speckyboy](http://speckyboy.com/2010/02/01/25-ui-inspiration-and-design-pattern-resources/)